# AutoCapture Screen views and button clicks events globally in without manually putting them on every screen and button

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, google-analytics, fragment

I was looking for some auto event capture for every screen and button clicks without manually putting them on every single button or Activity/Fragment and I could find few. But I am really curious to know what to going under the hood and how are they getting these info about screen views and button clicks.

Looking for some tips to create my custom auto capture events in Android App.

Answer (score 1):

You just have your tracking logic in global screen renderer, or button click listener, using whatever available there (screen ids, button ids, class names) to put in your events.

However, this only works if you don't hack around and always use the same methods for rendering and navigations.

Soon enough, the product owner will ask you to make a transparent screen, or to have a screen that flows from right to left, or a screen that opens only to a 1/3 of the screen, or a pop-up, or an overlay, or a weird iframe. You'll have to have defined tracking for those separately.

And then, on top of that, the Analytics team will donate their bit of discord where they don't want to see transparent screens as new screenviews, but also track red buttons differently from green ones. And Toggles should be tracked differently too. By the way, the screen class names aren't useful for analytics, please name them manually. And also, buttons that look like links should be tracked this special way. And don't track the buttons that are just  tooltips. Oh, the iframes. The iframes issue messages on activity in them, so listen to those and translate them to events please.

Now, this is an example of what it's going to be like. In real life, it's even more than that. If you have to add an exception for your universal tracking every time Analytics doesn't like it, you will end up with a mess of nested logic that is impossible to maintain. Also, every change to it will cause more bugs in unexpected places than fixes.

Still, universal tracking makes sense when you don't have dedicated analysts or a large marketing team and so you don't want to be able to answer complex business questions frequently.

In all other cases, it's better to hardcode analytics in a structured manner, maybe mapping screen ids to screen names in one neat place, then have analytics sdk wrappers to store the core logic and make use of the name mapping,